# How to classify unknown/unseen data as anomaly

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, anomaly-detection

I trained a CNN model with 6 different classes (labels are 0-5) and I am getting more than 90% accuracy out of it. It can correctly classify the classes. I am actually trying to detect anomaly with it. So what I want is, if any data comes which my model has never seen before or never been trained on similar data then it will be classified as anomaly. I do not have any abnormal data to train my model, I just have the normal data. So the rule would be, if any incoming data point does not belong to any of the six classes then it is anomaly. How can I do it?

I thought of a method which I am not sure if it works in this scenario. The method is, when I predict a single data point it gives me the probability score for all 6 classes. So, I take the maximum value out of this 6 value and if this max value is below a threshold level, for example, 70, then this observation will be classified as anomaly. That means, if any data point has less than 70% probability of being one of the six classes then it is an anomaly. The code looks like this

```
y_pred = s_model.predict(X_test_scaled)
normal = []
abnormal = []
max_value_list= []
for i in y_pred:
    max_value= np.max(i)
    max_value_list.append(max_value)
    if max_value <=0.70:
        abnormal.append(max_value)
        print('Anomaly detected')
    else:
        normal.append(max_value)

print('The number of total abnormal observations are: ',len(abnormal))
```

Does this method works in my case? Or is there any better way to do it? Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Detecting OOD is a research problem, not a programming one.

Comment: Any suggestions where I should ask this question? I tried cross validated but didn't get any answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting problem but I think your method does not work.

When your model's entropy is high, i.e. it is unsure which class to choose for that particular sample input, it does not necessarily mean that that sample is an anomaly, it just means that the model is perhaps struggling to select the correct **normal** class.

I suggest adding some abnormal samples (some random unrelated images, if your samples are images), between 1% to 10% of your data, and labelling them as `class 7`. Then train your model with those (and perhaps give more penalty for misclassifying the `class 7`).

When you have your unseen samples, you classify them using your trained model. If they are classified as `class 7`, then you know they are anomalies.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I didn't follow the part, giving more penalty for misclassifying the class 7. Could please elaborate. I am not really much experienced on this.

Comment: Don't worry about this part, your model will still be good. Implement without it and please accept my answer as a solution.

Comment: I tried the way you suggested. The random data I took are not really random but are from different categories which I want to label as anomaly. After training when I tested my model it detects many abnormal samples as one of the six classes, instead of 7
and also shows about 99% probability score of being one of the six classes. Does this mean those abnormal samples mostly looks like that of a normal samples? Could there be any other reason?